# How to have IntelliJ build a jar to a directory and then run a separate jar as a run config?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am developing plugins for Spigot and I want to be able to build and run them from the same place, with the server's output going into the terminal. How do I make IntelliJ place my jar in a plugins folder and then run the server jar outside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an artifact to build the jar to the directory and then make a run config that executes the other jar, and down at the bottom there is a list where you can have IntelliJ build the jar.